# Sending And Receiving SMS using a NetBeans application?

Tags: email, sms, send, notify

I'm making a software which is an inventory control. I need to send Text Messages to shop owner's phone when an employee logged on to the system. But I'm new to java and don't have a much knowledge. Can someone help me? I need java code and the instructions on how to do it. Much appreciate your help.

Comment: This is a good question for me +1 .. Please if you found any answer or helpful tutorial inform me thank you so much :)